# Make List of Numbers

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm using VB 2010 express.  How do I create a list of numbers in a listbox from a value in a textbox.  For example, if the textbox is "15" then the listbox would be "1", "2", "3"...."15"  I would like each number to be on its own line in the listbox.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Private Sub PopulateList(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim list As String() = New String(-1) {}
    Dim str As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Integer.TryParse(str, count)

    If (count > 0) Then
        list = New String((count - 1)) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To (count - 1)
            list(i) = (i + 1).ToString()
        Next
    End If

    Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.ListBox1.Items.AddRange(list)

End Sub
```

Comment: This code worked well when I plugged it into my project.  Thanks.  But I'm new to VB, so could you annotate the lines to explain what you did.  I'm having trouble interpreting it.